# PHP performance to check user right and get file from other servers

Tags: php, sql, performance, google-cloud-storage, query-optimization

I have a project and I am currently using Google storage to store photos.
You can access a photo through a PHP (because it need a Google authentication) but this one is called a lot like ten times in one action (gallery load)

Database « structure »
Photographer can have multiple clients, client can have multiple galleries and gallery has photos

Photos has `<FileName>` which be send to the « download.php » to retrieve it from Google Cloud Storage and return a response `image/jpeg` containing the image data

Currently you can send something like « download.php?key=hekavg71948hdk_img7291.jpg» and the download.php will return the file from the google cloud or 404 if there is no file corresponding to that name (without going in database query for that) so anyone without being logged can access to a photos (photos only) through this php

I was wondering adding a user check to verify if the Photographer/client is the owner of the requested file will be a good idea (like check if the file come from a gallery that comes from a client which is the current user) or it will take too much time to transfer a file? Cause retrieve it from google is a bit longer (like 600ms/image with good network) and making a similar query takes 12ms with the server and the database on the same server

What do you think?
Or at least check if the user is logged in without checking the if it's the owner or not.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by an "user check"? Why should that be relevant in terms of performance?

Comment: By user check i mean currently anyone can access anyones file if they send the correct random 60char as get param so user check is to verify of if the user is the owner of the requested file, iam asking that beacause « massive » files request is a bit slow due to cloud transfert so if i may add user check in database that will be more slower at a point that user will cancel the request

Comment: Please add all further explanation to the question itself, not to the comment section. And yes, if checking for the permission takes longer than downloading the file, that is not a good idea. But if you have to check for permissions anyways, I see no reason to skip this

Comment: @NicoHaase added !

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add another solution, OAuth 2.0 authentication to authenticate tools and applications (grant permission to them) to access Google Cloud Storage API on your behalf, access is restricted by OAuth scope devstorage.read_only, devstorage.read_write, and devstorage.full_control.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists
https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/07/09/five-minute-php-app-auth

Comment: Authentification for the user is already done and its effective only on my servers. The project is not a google storage client. Iam just using that as a storage server for my project who need a big amount of diskspace to work